# is It necessary to call ApplicationContext.start

Tags: spring

I found without using start method, I can still create beans. What's the main purpose of ApplicationContext.start()?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The start() method is required by the [Lifecycle interface](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/context/Lifecycle.html), which is [primarily used to support asynchronous processing](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?t=26664). You shouldn't need to call it on your main application context.

Comment: With this will this possible that we can write simple _Timer_ event.....? Rather not following & using some tricky product which divulges and play convulsions to processor.... In my case `Spring Quartz` which wasn't supported by my `JBoss` - `WorkManager`...... Or by some other options on & around `context` paradigm.....?