# what the usage of method start() in AbstractApplicationContext

Tags: spring

I'm a spring user. and I start to read the source code of spring.

when I read AbstractApplicationContext, I found there's one method start(), I found that the method doesn't be called when ApplicationContext is initialized.

My questions:
1)what the usage of the method? according to the word's(start) meaning, I think it should be called before the ApplicationContext can work. but it doesn't.

2)how can I listen the event which applicationContext starting working? after reading the code, I found the method will publish ContextStartedEvent. but if I just initialize the context, the context still can work and don't publish event.I can't listen the event to track the start of applicationcontext.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `start` method is part of the [Lifecycle](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/Lifecycle.html) interface, which is called as part of the application startup process.

If you want to be notified when the context is starting you should declare a bean that implements the Lifecycle interface.

```
public class org.example.MyLifecycle implements Lifecycle {
    private boolean started = false;
    public boolean isRunning() {
        return started;
    }
    public void start() {
        System.err.println("MyLifecycle starting");
        started = true;
    }
    public void stop() {
        System.err.println("MyLifecycle stopping");
        started = false;
    }
}
```

Then

```
<bean class="org.example.MyLifecycle"/>
```

This is all handled, by default, by [DefaultLifecycleProcessor](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/DefaultLifecycleProcessor.html) unless there's a bean in the context called `lifecycleProcessor` which implements the [LifecycleProcessor](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/LifecycleProcessor.html) interface

Comment: My understanding is the method is just a simple implementation for lifecycle? and for case when user don't define its own implementation?is it correct?

Comment: It's part of the `Lifecycle` interface used within Spring and which can also be used by your own classes, if it suits your needs. By default, if a bean registered in the context implements `Lifecycle` then it's `start` and `stop` methods will be called when necessary.

Typically an `ApplicationContext` need not be `start`ed in this way though. Calling `refresh` is most often enough. If you have components that need a lifecycle that matches the `Lifecycle` interface, then it's a good choice.

Comment: There's a slightly related question already http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5333189/is-it-neccesary-to-call-applicationcontext-start